# The term independent of $x$ in the expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

What is he term independent of $x$ in the expansion of 
$$
\Bigg[\left(\dfrac{x+1 }{ x^{2/3} - x^{1/3} + 1}\right ) - \left(\dfrac{x - 1 }{ x-x^{1/2}}\right)\Bigg]^{10}
$$

Comment: You do know the binomial theorem, yes?

Comment: Yea but i'm having problem in dealing with x^2/3 and x^1/3

Comment: Note that 1/x^2/3 should be read 1/(x^2)/3 which is presumably $\frac 1{3x^2}$ (or perhaps $\frac 3{x^2}$)and not what you meant.  Please use parentheses, or, preferably $\LaTeX$.  You can get some help [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I wrote the general term T(r+1)=nCr(x+1/x^2/3-x^1/3+1)^10-r-1)^r(x-1/x-x^1/2)^r

Comment: Its actually x^(2/3).I for got to use parenthesis.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what that expression's meant to be. Try using these to make your expression clearer: 1) Enclose the expression in dollar (\$) signs to format it, 2) \frac{a}{b} gives $\frac{a}{b}$, 3) e^{2x} gives $e^{2x}$

Comment: Please check that my edit didn't do undue violence to your intent, my answer and @exploringnet's start with very different interpretations.

Comment: @user71589 I hope you have got what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler proof:
Try to simplify.

$$
\begin{align*}
\left( \dfrac{x + 1}{x^{2/3} - x^{1/3} + 1} - \dfrac{x - 1}{x - x^{1/2}} \right)^{10}
  &= \left( 
       (x^{1/3} + 1) 
         - \dfrac{(\sqrt{x} - 1) (\sqrt{x} + 1)}{\sqrt{x} ( \sqrt{x} - 1)}
     \right)^{10} \\
  &= (x^{1/3} + 1 - 1 - x^{-1/2})^{10} \\
  &= (x^{1/3} - x^{-1/2})^{10}
\end{align*}
$$
The general term is:
$$
\binom{10}{r} x^{r/3} x^{-(10 - r)/2}
$$
So we want $r$ such that:
$$
\frac{r}{3} - \frac{10 - r}{2} = 0
$$
This gives $r = 6$, and the coefficient is $$\binom{10}{6} = \binom{10}{4} = 210$$

Comment: **Please** don't add images when LaTeX will do. _Please_ don't use that bletcherous notation for binomial coefficients, the civilized world has long agreed they are written `\binom{n}{k}` in LaTeX, rendered $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: @vonbrand If you can write it for me , please.

Comment: You owe me big time...

Comment: Yes! thank you.

Comment: The roots can be eliminated by the substitution $x \mapsto u^6$. The development will be essentially the same, just less root signs to make you pause...

Comment: @vonbrand Well in exam this substitution was first method in my brain but afterwards i simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the mess, substitute $x \mapsto u^6$, and multiply the parentesis through by $u^6$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( (u^6 + u^{-4} - u^{-2} + 1) - (u^6 - u^{-6} - u^{-3}) \right)^{10}
  &= u^{-60} (u^{12} + u^2 - u^4 + u^6 - u^{12} + 1 + u^3)^{10} \\
  &= u^{-60} (u^6 - u^4 + u^3 + u^2 + 1)^{10}
\end{align*}
$$
The only way to get $u^{60}$ is by $(u^6)^{10}$; by the binomial theorem its coefficient is 1.

Comment: You interpreted it wrong. Well you can solve it by this different approach again.

Comment: Yes of course you can extend your this approach to real question too.